# Deeply nested if statement remove PMD

Tags: java, pmd

How to remove below deeply nested if statement.

```
List<c1> list1 = new ArrayList();

    }
}
```

Comment: For future: this kind of "how can I improve this code" question would do better (and probably get better answers!) on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  . Stackoverflow is more for technical problems, rather than code improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think your real problem is that you / your application are over-using `null`, either deliberately or because you have lots of problems with uninitialized variables and arrays.

If you tracked down and eliminated the source of those nulls, you could get rid of all of those null checks that are making your code complex.  (In fact, I would be tempted to remove the checks anyway, and use the resulting NPEs to help you track down where the `null` values are coming from.)

To illustrate, this is what your code would look like if there were no `null`s to worry about:

```
Asset listthree = (Asset) getPIFObject(aModelManager, list2);
List<c1> list1 = listthree.getCoverageList();
for (Coverage abc : list1) {
    if (("eu".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd())) || 
        ("mn".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd())) ) {
        myCoverage = abc;
        break;
    }
}
```

(I've also removed an unnecessary test to see if `list1` is empty, and moved the declaration of `list1`.)

Answer (score 2):

Move the code into new methods.  The for-loop is a good candidate.  Once it's in its own method, you can make it simpler too: by returning `abc` as soon as you find a match:

```
private String find(List<c1> list1) {
        for (Coverage abc :list1) {
            if(null != abc){
                if(("eu".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd())) || ("mn".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd())) ){
                    return abc;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Then just call it from your existing code:

```
list1 = listthree.getCoverageList();
myCoverage = find(list1);
```

Have also removed the `if(!list1.isEmpty()){` check - that's not needed.  If the list is empty, the for-loop will be fine: it just won't do anything.

The final thing you can do is to make sure you actually need all those `null` checks.  If those values can never be null, then don't add the null check.

Comment: without creating method how i can fix this issue??

Answer (score 1):

As @StephenC said, the best option is to avoid to provide `null` values so that you can remove these null checks. However, if for some reason you can't be sure that no `null` values are provided and you have to keep these null checks you can refactor you code using `Optional`:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(list2)
        .map(f -> getPIFObject(aModelManager, list2))
        .map(a -> a.getCoverageList().stream())
        .orElse(Stream.empty())
        .filter(c -> "eu".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCoverageCd()) || "mn".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCoverageCd()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CoverageException("No coverage found !")); //or orElse(defaultValue);
```

If you are the caller of this method, then ensure to never pass `null` (instead give empty lists/default values/null objects) then your code could be dramatically simplified to:

```
Asset listthree = (Asset) getPIFObject(aModelManager, list2);
for (Coverage abc : listthree.getCoverageList()) {
    if (("eu".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd())) || ("mn".equalsIgnoreCase(abc.getCoverageCd()))) {
        return abc;
    }
}
throw new CoverageException("No coverage found !"); //or return a default value
```

This achieves the same behaviour as above but with `Optional`:

```
Asset listthree = (Asset) getPIFObject(aModelManager, list2);
return listthree.getCoverageList().stream()
        .filter(c -> "eu".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCoverageCd()) || "mn".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCoverageCd()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CoverageException("No coverage found !")); //or orElse(defaultValue);
```